# /etc/hosts for single process

Tags: linux, networking

Is it possible to set domain names mapping directly for an executable? As if we edit /etc/hosts/ and then run the executable.

Example:

```
$ ping google.com
PING google.com (74.125.232.48) 56(84) bytes of data.
$ magic-command -m google.com=127.0.0.1 ping google.com
PING google.com (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

Comment: Why? / What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Perhaps this should have been migrated to unix.SE instead of ServerFault?

Answer (score 5):

It is pissible to intercept most calls to libc with a creative usage of LD_PRELOAD and RTLD_NEXT. Google these strings, there's a lot of info out there. Intercept calls to `open`, substitute your own file for `/etc/hosts`. It should work.

Comment: Intercepting calls to `open()` might not work for this case. See http://plash.beasts.org/wiki/PlashFAQs. You might need to intercept `gethostbyname()` or its friends instead.